# How should we treat questions that break NDA?

Tags: discussion

How should we treat questions that break NDA? For instance: questions about Mac OS X Lion. Should we close them? Or just leave them be?

Comment: An additional question: are they reopenable after Lion's released?

Comment: Does any discussion of any kind regarding use of 10.7 break NDA? I doubt it's that #000000 and #FFFFFF

Comment: @TheWhitePhoenix: AFAIK it does. Best just stay away from it.

Comment: @Mark that makes me sad. Only because I'm totally not sold on the legal interpretation. My instinct says we're merely being intimidated. But, in fairness, if I were responsible for the site, I suppose, I'd probably encourage the path of certain safety too.

Comment: @TheWhitePhoenix: I agree, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't see any reason to allow NDA questions in this case.

I am more sympathetic on Stack Overflow where developers are working with final (but unreleased to end users) APIs that they need assistance with.

For consumer facing things like an OS, Software, Hardware, etc.. I see no benefit to allowing private NDA questions, since things *may* change before final release to consumers.